# Convert array elements into individual objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have the below array `arr` as follows

```
let arr = [
{ id: "12", value: "Rome" }, 
{ id: "24", value: "Egypt"} 
]
```

i want the following result. Can someone pls let me know how to achieve this.

```
[
   { id: "12" },
   { id: "24" }
]
```

Basically, i only want `id` properties in the final result. All other properties inside that object should be ignored.

Comment: you actually get `{0: "12", 1: "24", 2: "36"}` for `obj`. Neither what you wrongly say you get, or what you say you want, are valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: Expected result is not valid, Every object must be pair of `key - vale`.

Comment: it's almost like you want `obj = arr.map(v => [v])`

Comment: @JaromandaX- My bad, i totally got this wrong. i updated my question

Comment: @RobinZigmond- m sorry, i got it wrong. updated my question.

Comment: so `obj = arr.map(({id}) => ({id})}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you want to do is iterate over the existing array of objects and only return a specific portion of that object as your end result for the new ones.

This can be done using `.map`, which will return an array of objects with only the `id` property from the original array.

```
let onlyIdArr = arr.map(obj => ({ id: obj.id }))
```